# Is It There Any Way To Prevent Users From Creating God Mode Folders

Tags: windows, security, group-policy, godmode

we were working on a small company where IT policy have been implemented with restrictions like disabling wallpaper changes etc,

But recently one of my company employee have just created godmode folder in windows 7 and bypassed/removed some restrictions like wallpaper change,accessing group policy registry etc.

Is it there any way to prevent domain users from creating god mode folders at windows 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### How can I stop users creating God Mode folders?

This can be done using **Group Policy** settings for "Control Panel".

1. Open "Group Policy"
2. Navigate to the "Control Panel" setting.

   - Windows Server 2008 and above:

     "User Configuration" > "Policies" > "Administrative Templates" > "Control Panel"
   - Windows Server 2003:

     "User Configuration" > "Administrative Templates" > "Control Panel"
3. Click on the container called "Control Panel"
4. Double click "Prohibit Access To The Control Panel", set to "Enabled", then click "OK"

This will remove "Control Panel" from the start menu and prevent user access to "Control Panel".

If the user runs `GodMode` it will show an empty file explorer.

Users are still able to access "Printers and Devices" and "Administrative Tools".

---

#### Further reading

- [Block access to Windows 7 God Mode](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/12040-block-access-to-windows-7-god-mode)

Comment: This probably won't prevent users from changing the same things using cmd or powershell or some other programmatic solution, right?

Comment: @mbomb007 Correct, of course.